# Увеличение значения в ассоциативном массиве

Tags: php, массивы

Добрый день, вроде нетривиальная задача, но что-то не могу въехать. В общем, у меня в цикле из БД вытаскиваются значения, нужно запихнуть их в ассоциативный массив, при чем посчитать повторы, я хочу это делать примерно так:

if ($str=='1') $mas['один'] +=1;

if ($str=='2') $mas['два'] +=1;

Ну и в этом духе. Но дело в том, что вместо того, чтобы увеличилось значение счетчика ассоциативного массива, добавляется еще дополнительная пара ключ=>значение, а нужно просто переписать, увеличив значение на единичку... Как это сделать?

Comment: Нетривиальная - в смысле тривиальная?

Comment: приведите нормальный пример кода.

Comment: у вас в массиве становится два ключа `один` или как ?

Comment: Именно, если $str еще раз единичка, и выполняется $mas['один'] +=1; то на выходе имею два ключа "один"

Comment: вы приведите, пожалуйста, пример кода [mcve]

Comment: Вообще проблем не наблюдается https://pastebin.com/zDDDa2tC

Comment: Какая основная задача подсчитать повторы ? Если так то решение выдергивать записи по одной  в цикле и прибавлять счетчик не самая лучшая достаточно тогда сделать один запрос правильный 
SELECT name, COUNT(*) c FROM table GROUP BY name HAVING c > 1; И выполучите количество повторов одним запросом.

Answer (score 1):

Если твой массив рождается уже в цикле и не назначен до него то было-бы не плохо его определять

... цыкл ...

```
if(!isset($mas)){
      $mas = array();
};

if($str=='1'){
   if(!isset($mas['один'])){
      $mas['один'] = 1;
   }else{
      $mas['один'] +=1;
   };
};

if($str=='2'){
   if(!isset($mas['два'])){
      $mas['два'] = 1;
   }else{
      $mas['два'] +=1;
   };
};
```

... // цыкл ...